# Integrate Google+ & Linkedin In Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, linkedin-api, google-plus, blackberry-jde

How to integrate Google+ and linked-in my blackberry App. Is there any SDK or API available to integrate Google+ and linked-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even try to Google them?

These came top of the google searches for 'Google+ API' and 'Linkedin API' when I tried

https://developers.google.com/+/api/

https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

For both of them you will need a BlackBerry OAuth library, try googling that one yourself, there are a few options available.

If you have any problems using the API's or OAuth please ask a new question giving the specific details of the problem and someone will possibly try to help.